# I'm trying to get a script to rename files via an oldname and newname in a CSV file, but can't get it to work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to Python, but have tried creating a script that looks at a CSV file, and takes the values in cells in column 3, finds that filename in the directory, and then renames it from the relevant value in column 5.

I thought it might be a permissions problem, but even when I run it with files locally nothing happens.

```
import os, sys, csv

IDs = {}
with open ('/Path to CSV file/ArchiveListCSV.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    timeReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')

    for row in timeReader:
        IDs[ row[3] ]= row[5]

path = 'Path to files to be renamed/'

for oldname in os.listdir(path):
    if oldname in IDs:
        try:
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, oldname), os.path.join(path, IDs[oldname]))
        except:
            print('File ' + oldname + ' could not be renamed to ' + IDs[oldname] + '!')
```

When I run it I get no error messages, but the files aren't renamed. I just want it to rename all the files it finds from the valus in column 3 in the CSV, to the relevant value in column 5.

Comment: put a logging/print inside your try block. how are you sure that's even being hit??

Comment: I've tried this but no result. There must be something up with the try block. The files definitely exist though. When I print the ID dictionary the keys and values are all correct.

Comment: Without seeing the ouputs, I can see 3 potential reasons: 1) `os.listdir(path)` is empty or 2) No file in path match the names in `IDs` 3) `IDs[oldname]` is equal to `oldname`. Try printing the outputs at different stages and see if everything seems normal.

Comment: I think the problem ~may~ be the extension (.mpg) in the filename. Is there a way I can get 'oldname' it no include the .mpg extension in the filename?

Comment: `oldname[:-4]` will return the name without ext. I think there's an `os` method that's more reliable as well.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the try block.  print the old and new names INSIDE the try statement and lets see what it gives you out.

Comment: old files do not share the same path as `path` variable? but this should hit your error handler.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example, your code works well if I set up my own example. Your path variable must not be pointing to files in your csv dict. You can do `for file in os.listdir(path): file = os.splittext(file)[0]` to get the name without the extension

Comment: Thanks guys. I've managed to get it to find the files in the directory. So now I get the 'except' section printing out. So the 11 files are found, but can't be renamed. Any ideas?

Sorry I've only been learning Python for a few days, so I'm learning from all this. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: So I've figured it out. Thanks for your help guys. Just added ```[:-4]``` to every mention of ```oldname``` when referenced in the ```IDs``` dict.

Comment: can't rename is likely a permissions issue (i.e., the user or program doesn't have write access to one or both directories). alternatively maybe file of same name already exists on the new location.